# Provide two different notices for one controller action depending on redirect from path in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3

I edit and update my Profile object in two different places and would like to serve a specific notice for each. For example, when I edit/update the Profile in `settings_path` I'd like to say something like "Updated user information successfully". When I edit/update the Profile in `join_path` I'd like to say something like "Profile created" or nothing at all.

Is something like this possible?

Here's my `Profiles#update` action:

```
def update
  @profile = user.profile
  if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
    redirect_to profile_path, :notice => 'Updated user information successfully.'
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check to see where the form was posted from using `request.referrer`, e.g.

```
def update
  @profile = user.profile
  if @profile.update_attributes(params[:profile])
    if request.referrer == settings_path
      notice_message = 'Updated user information successfully'
    elsif request.referrer == join_path
      notice_message = 'Profile created'
    else
      notice_message = 'Profile Updated'  # default message
    end

    redirect_to profile_path, :notice => notice_message
  else
    render :edit
  end
end
```

That code can be cleaned up quite a lot but that's the generate theme of it.

Comment: I took what you had but it didn't work for some reason. Wrapping request.referrer in URI - `URI(request.referrer).path == "/signup/join"` though did. Thanks!